# Laravel console command - Ask for a non required (optional) input

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to create a optional console command.

```
$phone = $this->ask('Enter a phone number for the Seller (blank if not supplied)');
```

The problem is that if left blank I'll get:

> [ERROR] A value is required.

Is there a work around for this to not require a response? Maybe something like `->nullable()` or similar?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

By default answer to console question is required. Empty string is considered an empty answer, hence the error. You need to provide a default value and that should do the trick.

Try the following:

```
$phone = $this->ask('Enter a phone number for the Seller (blank if not supplied)', false);
```

If no phone number has been provided it will be given **FALSE** value. You can see if number was provided with

```
if ($phone !== FALSE) { //notice strict comparison !==
  // number has been provided
} else {
  // no number provided
}
```

Comment: Works perfect. Thanks